# How to run my view function without reload page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

How to run my view function without reload page?

**views:**

```
def set_prio(request, id):
    obj = Object.objects.get(id=id)
    obj.prio = True
    obj.save()
    #return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

**templates:**

```
<a href="/set-prio/{{g.id}}" class="star star--off"></a>
```

Comment: What? a page redirect without a reload ?

Comment: Ajax! Are you asking how to use Ajax with jQuery?

Comment: Please show us jquery code

Comment: @minitech yes, I'm asking how to use ajax with django

Comment: -1: Then that should be your question. Be explicit about you are asking and don't just put a bunch of code.

Comment: If you are looking for a redirect, you might aswell have a simple form submit. You are not doing anything fancy here

Comment: @karthikr: Sorry, `HttpResponseRedirect` can be deleted. I need to change the value to `True` only.

Answer (score 1):

Run it using an ajax request and apply the result of your request using javascript.
Here is an example: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
And yes, your quesion should be much more explicit!